# Difference between features in Sharepoint 2007 and 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, migration

I've an easy question for you.. If I have some features written and running under Sharepoint 2007, is it possible to use the same features under Sharepoint 2010?
The features has to be written in the same way? There are no changes between the source in the different versions?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  Most features/solutions written for SharePoint 2007 should work fine in 2010 unless there was functionality that was only available in 2007.  Depending on your environment, if solutions are required to run as a sandbox solution in 2010, then there may be things in your feature that will not work.  There is a ton of information available to look at about sandbox solutions if that applies to you.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798382.aspx) is a starting point that may help.

The best way to find out for sure if your feature will work moving from 2007 to 2010 is to test it in a development environment such as a local VM.  A good test plan with associated test cases will help in your determination if it is working correctly.